# Retrieve one item per group from one tabel with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with tweets from different users where I'd like to select the latest tweet per person. What sql do I use to retrieve these?

```
twitter_username   tweet       date
stevdobb           tweet one   2013-06-07 12:00
stevdobb           tweet two   2013-06-09 12:00   
stevdobb           tweet three 2013-06-05 12:00
other_username     tweet four  2013-06-10 12:00
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get create a subquery to find the latest date by user

```
select twitter_username, max(date) from tweets group by twitter_username
```

Then you can use this subquery to get the required tweets

```
select tweets.* from tweets join ( 
   select twitter_username, max(date) max_date 
   from tweets group by twitter_username
) latest on 
latest.twitter_username = tweets.twitter_username and 
latest.max_date = tweets.date
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT twitter_username,tweet FROM your_table
GROUP BY `twitter_username` ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

GROUP BY is usually used with aggregate functions, but without them, only the first matching record is shown. If you order it by date desc, it is the latest one.

Comment: This returns all the tweets from every user. I just want the last tweet per user.